# Replace range of colors on HTML5 Canvas?

Tags: javascript, text, colors, html5-canvas

I'm having an issue with a timestamp i'm burning on to photos using canvas.

Currently, I am coloring it cyan then applying a difference filter to account for similar colors in the background. However, when the background is gray, the difference filter doesn't resolve this issue, and the timestamp can become unreadable.

Is it possible to look for a range of colors after the filter only on the text and replace those colors? I'm thinking look for a range of gray, then replace that range with pure black or white.

I've done lots of looking around but can only seem to find instructions on how to apply a filter like this to the whole image, not just the text.

Here's an example I made of how it kind of looks now, But on the real code I'm using webcam input, so the image drawing is slightly different.

```js
var image = new Image();
image.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFBxY.png";
image.onload = draw;

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function drawImage(img, x, y, filter) {
  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.filter = filter
  ctx.drawImage(img, x, y);
  ctx.closePath()
}

ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "difference";
ctx.fillStyle = "cyan";
ctx.fillText("Hello World!", 150, 100);

function draw() {
  drawImage(image, 0, 0, 'none');
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=500></canvas>
```

Comment: A fully functional example showing that issue "the timestamp can become unreadable" can help us help you ... with that code you provided will be very hard to help

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell exactly what is happening in your case.
...but here is an idea, we can drop a "shadow" of the text to make it pop.
what I would do is write the text twice but with a bit of an offset

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=500></canvas>

<script>
    var pixelated = null
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFBxY.png";
    image.onload = draw;

    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    function drawImage(img, x, y, filter) {
        ctx.beginPath()
        ctx.filter = filter
        ctx.drawImage(img, x, y);
        ctx.closePath()
    }

    function drawText(text, x, y) {
        ctx.font = "60px Verdana";
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.fillText(text, x + 2, y + 2);
        ctx.fillStyle = "cyan";
        ctx.fillText(text, x, y);
    }

    function draw() {
        drawImage(image, 0, 0, 'blur(1px)');
        drawImage(image, 140, 0, 'none');
        drawText("Hello World!", 40, 80)
    }
</script>
```

Here is how it looks with just one:
[image]

Here is how it looks with two:
[image]

---

And I think that works fine for small fonts too, much better than:   `globalCompositeOperation = "difference";`
That makes it a very weird looking text...

Here is with small font and writing the text with two offset by one pixel each

```js
var image = new Image();
image.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFBxY.png";
image.onload = draw;

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function drawImage(img, x, y) {
  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.drawImage(img, x, y);
  ctx.closePath()
}

function drawText(text, x, y) {
    ctx.shadowColor = "black";
    ctx.shadowBlur = 2;
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillText(text, x + 1, y + 1);
    ctx.fillText(text, x - 1, y - 1);
    ctx.fillStyle = "cyan";
    ctx.fillText(text, x, y);
}

function draw() {
  drawImage(image, 0, 0);
  drawText("Hello World!", 10, 10);
  drawText("Hello World!", 50, 50);
  drawText("Hello World!", 150, 100);
  
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=500></canvas>
```

Comment: Sorry, I'll see if I can write up a code sample, this wouldn't work for me because the text size is very small, so shadows either don't do much, or become extremely distracting to the image.

Comment: I've updated my comment with a snippet if you want to check it out.

Comment: I update my answer too, I think that shadows do fine with small, but such a small font is certainly not good for reading

Comment: I want the "weird text" using the difference filter. The only problem with it is when presented with gray pixels it becomes less readable due to how the difference filter works, so I am wanting to know how to specify a color range and replace that range with a specified color.